# Re-arranging numbers using batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, random

On windows command line, is it possible to re-arrange numbers at random?

For example, I have the following logic in a batch file, where it selects numbers from s at random. This is allowing repeat items. I would like to have the items non-repeating.

```
@echo off

set i=
set s=12345678
set m=0
:loop
set /a n=%random% %% 8
call set i=%i%%%s:~%n%,1%%
set /a m=m+1
if not %m%==8 goto loop:
echo %i%

pause
```

Actual output: 83254646

The desired output would be something like: 83254176

Thanks,
Joel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following randomly selects a digit from the source string, and then removes that digit from the source. It avoids the relatively slow GOTO, and performs the minimum number of iterations.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "s=12345678"
set "i="
for /l %%N in (8 -1 1) do (
  set /a "n1=!random! %% %%N, n2=n1+1"
  for /f "tokens=1,2" %%A in ("!n1! !n2!") do (
    set "i=!i!!s:~%%A,1!"
    set "s=!s:~0,%%A!!s:~%%B!"
  )
)
echo !i!
pause
```

Comment: I think this logic will work best for my project since "s" isn't restricted to just numbers. It could contain any string and/or other variables that I set. Example: "s=%i1%%i2%%i3%". Thanks dbenham.

Answer (score 4):

this is imo faster (better with `delayed expansion`, I know but don't like it here):

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
for /l %%a in (1 1 8) do call set "$%%random%%%%a=%%a"
for /f "tokens=2delims==" %%a in ('set "$"') do <nul set/p"=%%a"
echo(
```

---

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
for /l %%a in (1 1 8) do call set "$%%random%%%%a=%%a"
for /f "tokens=2delims==" %%a in ('set "$"') do call set "line=%%line%%%%a"
echo(%line%
```

Comment: +1 - Good practical and efficient solution, though I would definitely use delayed expansion. Not needed here because restricted to single digits, but if the numbers expand to 2 or more digits, then need to insert a non-numeric character like `_` between the random number and the value. Otherwise could miss values due to duplicates. For example 12_1 and 1_21 would be duplicate without the `_`. This solution ever so slightly favors low numbers before high numbers because duplicate random numbers will always put low before high. But that isn't worth worrying about from a practical standpoint.

Answer (score 2):

you can put the number already done in  an associative array:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
set "i="
set "s=12345678"
:loop
set /a n=%random% %% 8
if not defined $%n% (
    call set "i=%i%%%s:~%n%,1%%"
    set "$%n%=1"
)  else (
    goto:loop
)
set /a m+=1
if not %m%==8 goto:loop
echo %i%
```

Comment: Not an optimal solution because the number of iterations varies randomly. Probably not noticeable with only 8 values to choose from, but as the number of choices grows, it becomes more and more likely that it will be unacceptably slow.

Comment: But still its a batch script. Batch scripts arent known for their optimal speed.